# Create multiple markers on map works, but only remember the last marker

Tags: java, android

i use tho code to add markers on my map. The problem is that if i create more than one marker, i can see all my markers on map, but if i exit the app and reopen, it only remember the last marker. I think i must create an array list and a loop. Unfortunately i was not able to find example on how to do this, i think is also because i use Mapsforge 0.3.1 and not Google map.

This is outside onCreate

```
ListOverlay myListOverlay;
List<OverlayItem> myOverlayItems;
Marker myMarker = null;
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
```

This is the code in the onCreate

```
myListOverlay = new ListOverlay();
myOverlayItems = myListOverlay.getOverlayItems();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myListOverlay);

prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MotionEvent",MODE_PRIVATE); 
    //Check whether your preferences contains any values then we get those values
    if((prefs.contains("Lat")) && (prefs.contains("Lon"))){   

        String lat = prefs.getString("Lat","");
        String lon = prefs.getString("Lon", ""); 

        GeoPoint l =new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lon));
        myMarker = createMarker(l, R.drawable.ic_location);
        myOverlayItems.add(myMarker);
            byte viewMarker =   this.mapView.getMapViewPosition().getZoomLevel();
            this.mapView.getMapViewPosition().setZoomLevel(viewMarker); 
            this.mapView.getMapViewPosition().setCenter(l);
    } 

mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {


            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    byte viewMarker =   mapView.getMapViewPosition().getZoomLevel();
                    float x = e.getX();
                    float y = e.getY();
                    GeoPoint gPt = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)x,   (int)y);
                    myMarker = createMarker(gPt, R.drawable.ic_location);
                    myOverlayItems.add(myMarker);
                    mapView.getMapViewPosition().setZoomLevel(viewMarker); 
                    prefs.edit().putString("Lat",String.valueOf(gPt.latitude)).commit();
                    prefs.edit().putString("Lon",String.valueOf(gPt.longitude)).commit();

                    DialogMyMarkers();



                 }



        }

    });

    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v0, MotionEvent e) {

            // Only fires if Mapview touched
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        }


    });
```

DialogMyMarkers open an edit text to give a name for the marker. Then the name of the marker is saved and show in the myMarkersDialog

```
     protected void myMarkersDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_markers_listview, null);
        builder.setView(convertView);
        builder.setTitle("List");
        lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         if (prefs.contains("Name"))
          {
             String name = prefs.getString("Name", "0");
                String[] values = new String[] {name};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

          }

    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
           }

        });


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
            }
```

But how can i do this when i have more than one marker on map?

Answer (score 0):

i think the error saty on line:

```
myListOverlay = new ListOverlay();
myOverlayItems = myListOverlay.getOverlayItems();
```

Why you need to recreate the overlay?

Advice: write on GoogleMaps V2 is easier!

Comment: Hello, i need that to add markers on map. I use maps forge cause i use offline maps

Answer (score 0):

Yes your assumption is correct  ***i think is also because i use Mapsforge 0.3.1 and not Google map*** you can use the Google Map API's and try to store the marker information using the sql-lite database . i think you will get the required output

go through this example [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use Mapsforge cause i need offline maps. Do i thins i can use Google map api's with Mapsforge?

Comment: i guess you cant use it with the Mapsforge. Have you tried storing the marker information in the sql-lite database

Comment: No, i haven't try yet to use sql-lite. It would be better for me if i can do it without use a db.

Comment: because i have also got this issue for the markers with the google maps but i have used to sql-lite database to store the marker positions, so even after closing and coming back to the application again the data was available.. so just give a try

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know if i can get some samples around the web?

Comment: you can refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) for the DB example for android...

Comment: Thank you. i will have a look.

Comment: yap.. just try to store the marker info in the db and just have a look do it make a difference..